# Twitter OAuth Swift OS X

Tags: cocoa, swift

I'm trying to integrate Twitter OAuth into my OS X app with Swift. I am getting a request token from the Twitter API and then using the app's protocol as the callbackURL `appname://oauth`.

I have seen a tutorial for iOS that uses something like this and then passes the request token from the `url` to then get the access token.

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String, annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
    // Fetch access token
    return true
}
```

Which was added to `AppDelegate.swift`.

As I understand, this won't work as Cocoa doesn't have `UIApplication`.

Can anyone help me adjust the above code for OS X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have to register your app's protocol (urlScheme) in its info.plist file.  Assuming you have done that.  You'll want to do something like the following in the app delegate:

```
let eventManager = NSAppleEventManager.sharedAppleEventManager()
eventManager.setEventHandler(self, andSelector:
                             Selector("handleEvent:withReplyEvent:"),
                             forEventClass: AEEventClass(kInternetEventClass),
                             andEventID: AEEventID(kAEGetURL))
```

Where Selector("handleAppleEvent") maps to a function name

```
func handleEvent(event: NSAppleEventDescriptor!, withReplyEvent: NSAppleEventDescriptor!) {
    println("Check the event for info")
}
```